# Pipe delimited output

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the below code that I need the format in pipe delimited format. I tried adding +'|' but seems I am not putting that correctly so it keeps on throwing errors. It can't be a stored procedure because of the rights. Also, I cannot change the result output permanently so can't use the tools-options menu. Could someone please add the pipe correctly for me in the below select statement. Thanks a ton. I am so confused.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
Name,
CAST(DOB AS DATE) AS DateOfBirth,
Address1 AS AddressStreet1,
Address2 AS AddressStreet2,
City AS AddressCity,
State AS AddressState,
Postal AS AddressZip,
Sex AS Gender,
CAST(ActivityDateTime AS DATE) AS ActivityDate,
CASE
    WHEN ID IN ('R','A')
    THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS Allow
```

Comment: can write an Output?

Comment: I was going to create an output but JonB code explains it below. That is exactly what I am trying to. However, I also need to have column names. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure if this is what you're looking for, but one option is to throw all of the fields into one with a pipe between them. The `UNION ALL` allows you to display the headers in the first row.

```
SELECT 'Name|DateOfBirth|AddressStreet1|AddressStreet2|AddressCity|AddressState|AddressZip|Gender|ActivityDate|Allow' AS Data
UNION ALL
SELECT  DISTINCT
Name + '|' +
CAST(DOB AS DATE) + '|' +
Address1 + '|' +
Address2 + '|' +
City + '|' +
State + '|' +
Postal + '|' +
Sex + '|' +
CAST(ActivityDateTime AS DATE) + '|' +
CASE
    WHEN ID IN ('R','A')
    THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END
AS Data
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, this is exactly what I need. However, I need the column names as well.

Comment: @sky_limit, Hrmm. I'm not sure how that could be achieved unless you have a separate statement that displays them for you. Doing that would be a separate query though.

Comment: I am trying to run a small script and scheduled it to run daily using SQL Server Agent. I can do CSV format. However, the result still gets messed up in the CSV format.

Comment: Is everything automated or are you pasting everything in? And if you're using Excel, you can use one of the tools in it to delimit the results by the pipe so the results separate into individual cells.

Comment: @sky_limit, if you see my updated answer I figured out how you could go about adding the headers to the first row.

Comment: I don't understand why it says, "The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.". I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I will convert the data type and re-run the query. Anyways, I was thinking of using CONCAT function now since + gives me null rows sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: @sky_limit, I wasn't thinking about that. In your query you're casting the date fields as dates. You do have the option to just cast them as varchars instead. For the null rows, that can happen when a field is nullable but you can check on that and set the fields to default values if they're null. :-)

Comment: Your answer works but I used CONCAT and that worked better. Thanks a lot.